# How could I get self object from python class in robotframework

Tags: python, oop, robotframework

Engine.py will import several classes as self object

`Engine.py`

```
from api import api
from cloud import cloud
class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self, env):
        session = dict()
        self.api = api.API(session)
        self.cloud= cloud.CLOUD(session)
```

`api.py`

```
class API(object):
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    def api_keyword(self):
        return SOMETHING
```

My question is :

How can I use the keyword under api.py and cloud.py and ONLY import Engine.py into robot file

`test.robot`

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Engine.py  ${env}


*** Test Cases ***
python class test
    [Tags]    class
    Engine.api.api_keyword
```

And I got error message:

No keyword with name 'Engine.api.api_keyword' found.

Comment: There isn't much you can do at the robot test level. Are you able to change `Engine.py`?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, I can change Engine.py. And I need to let API and XCLOUD share self.session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robot Framework maps only class methods to keywords; your class `Engine` does not expose any methods from `api` and `cloud` - it probably uses them internally, but doesn't define any as its own.
So here's your first solution - create wrapper methods for all you need in the cases:

```
def an_api_method(self):
    self.api.something()
```

And now you'll have the `An API Method` keyword at your disposal in the cases.

---

Solution two - make your class inherit the other two:

```
class Engine(api, cloud):
```

, and your cases will have access to **all** their public methods.
This one is more involving - you'll have to call their constructors (with `super()`), and if you maintain a state in *your* class, you'll have to accommodate for that. I.e. more drastic code changes are needed.

---

The third solution doesn't require any changes to the `Enhine` code - but, **disclaimer:** I don't know will it work :) (I'm not at a computer).
It consists of two calls - first to use `Get Library Instance` to get the object of your imported library (from the Builtin library), and then - `Call Method`:

```
${ref}=     Get Library Instance    Engine
Call Method     $ref.api    api_keyword
```